# Why can't removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

[code link](http://jsbin.com/zotowagemu/edit?html,output)

I want to remove mouseover event when mouseup event triggers, but why can't revomeEventListener and how to fix it,looks like this is my weak part in javascript.

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question, no links to code, to improve the chances of getting a high quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fnDown you set the event listener to be on the **dragBox** but then you try to remove it from the **dragArea** later on. You need to attach the listener to the **dragArea** if that's where you plan to remove it from. This function works as expected.

```
    Drag.prototype.fnDown = function (e) {
        this.diff.x = e.clientX - this.dragBox.offsetLeft
        this.diff.y = e.clientY - this.dragBox.offsetTop
        this.dragArea.addEventListener('mousemove', this.fnMove,false)
    }
```

Working example:
http://jsbin.com/dugoxeziho/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks,I'm too careless to find out it